# How do I write x like this? (vector, linear algebra)

Tags: math-mode

How do I write x like this (left-hand side of the equation)?
[image]

As you see it must be a notation for a vector in linear algebra. Is this notation commonly used? Or it's author's preference to use this notation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: `\mathbf` though, I'd recommend `\bm` from the package `bm` it gives bold italic which I feel is more appropriate.

Comment: thank you both!

Comment: B.t.w., this is a matter of personal taste, but I prefer a bold italic font for x; obtainable with the `bm` package, and the eponymous command `\bm{x}`.

Comment: There is also \textbf{x}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo there is but it would be wrong to use in math (almost always)